# My class for key binding dosent work

Tags: java, swing, class

I wanted to make my keybinding look abit more elegant in the main so i made a keybinding class, its not working though... anyone know why?
i recently made a moveover from keylistners to keybindings and just got to understand how they work though maybe i dont understand it 100% 
it would be nice to get an explanation of why the class wont work and exactly what the inputmap and actionmap have to do with the binding and how they all fit together to make the code respond to keystroke [ there are explanations online though not thorough enough]
 Thanks!

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class movement {
    private JComponent jt;
    private InputMap ip;
    private ActionMap ap;
    private String comm;
    private KeyStroke key;
    private int movement;
public movement(JComponent jt, InputMap ip,ActionMap ap, String comm,KeyStroke key,int movement){
    this.jt = jt;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.ap= ap;
    this.comm = comm;
    this.key = key;
    this.movement = movement;
}
public void newAction(){
    this.ip  = this.jt.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    this.ip.put(key, comm);
    this.ap = this.jt.getActionMap();
    this.ap.put(this.comm, new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            jt.setBounds(jt.getX()+movement,jt.getY() , 50, 50);

        }
    });

}
}

This is the main method:
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.awt.image.ImageProducer;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.management.openmbean.KeyAlreadyExistsException;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Malario {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("malario");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(700, 700);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    JLabel malario = new JLabel("Malario");
    malario.setOpaque(true);
    malario.setBackground(Color.green);
    panel.add(malario);

    malario.setBounds(100, 550, 50, 50);

    JLabel platform = new JLabel();
    platform.setOpaque(true);
    platform.setBounds(0,600,700,50);
    panel.add(platform);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    final int originalx = 100;
    final int originaly = 550;
    int currentlocx = originalx;
    int currentlocy = originaly;

movement moveRight = new movement(malario, new InputMap(), new ActionMap(), "move Right",KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,0) , 10);
```

Comment: Where do you call `moveRight.newAction()`? By the way, the Java convention is that class names should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: `there are explanations online though not thorough enough` - Did you download the working example from the tutorial link I provide your with? (your welcome for the help by the way - check the edit in my answer for a working example) Or, did you search the forum for other working examples?